# Linux, how to create file using directory name?

Tags: linux, directory

How to create folders like: wdw/1/11, wdw/2/22, ... wdw/6/66, ..., wdw/9/99, and file using directory name in the deepest directory like directoryname_file.txt

Comment: To create a directory you use the `mkdir(2)` syscall, to create files you use the `open(2)` syscall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash:

```
mkdir wdw                                    # Creates the top dir.
mkdir {1..9}                                 # Creates the subdirs using brace expansion.
for dir in {1..9} ; do
    mkdir $dir/$dir$dir                      # Creates the subsubdirs.
    touch $dir/$dir$dir/$dirdir"_file".txt   # Creates the file.
done
```

Comment: @ŁukaszOgan: OK. What *can* you use?

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you can use the mkdir command:

```
your_dir="wdw/1/11"
if [ ! -d $your_dir ]; then
    mkdir $your_dir
fi
```

The IF clause is to check if the directory already exists.
You can loop to change the value of "your_dir" with /2/22, 6/66, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have use the `-p` flag with `mkdir` to create nested directories, for example:

```
dir_name="wdw/1/11"
mkdir -p $dir_name
```

Then use `touch` or `echo` to create the files:

```
touch $dir_name/directoryname_file.txt
```

or

```
echo "some text" > $dir_name/directoryname_file.txt
```

Comment: You need to redirect, not pipe, the output from `echo` into a file.